# Chordal Analysis of Christian Petzold's Minuet in G (formerly attributed to J.S. Bach)

Tags: theory, composition, analysis

The piece I am asking about is the well-known minuet that was originally attributed to J.S. Bach but has since been re-attributed to lesser-known composer, Christian Petzold.

My question concerns harmonic analysis: in measure fifteen, can beats two and three be considered as implying a I6/4 chord?

The page discussing the re-attribution can be found [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuet_in_G_major_%28BWV_Anh._114%29)

[The score can be found here.](http://petrucci.mus.auth.gr/imglnks/usimg/b/b6/IMSLP212448-PMLP06107-AMBach_Menuets_G_114_115.pdf)

Comment: PDF of score on muse score: http://static.musescore.com/52405/a8eec6ad1b/score.pdf

Comment: Current form looks good, I'll reopen and clean up comments.

Answer (score 1):

My original response was put in a comment, but as the question has now been reopened, I'll post the answer here:

The passage in question does not imply a I6/4 chord. It outlines a V chord. The "B" on beat two is an upper-neighboring tone and the "G" on beat three is a passing tone - what could be seen as a 4-3 suspension.

Also, an analysis of I6/4 is incomplete as the cadence actually occurs on the downbeat of the following measure, and cadences do not occur in weird or asymmetric configurations at this point in music history.

Hope that helps.